# Concat inside IFNULL

Tags: mysql, concatenation, ifnull

I have a statement

```
SELECT CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName, '', IFNULL(middleName, ''))
```

which works fine, it gives me all names whether there's a middle name or not. My problem is that I don't want to include the empty space after the first name for records without a middle name, if that's possible. How can I only add the space after the first name when there is a middle name?

Comment: @wchiquito This is exactly the answer given by Jorge, q.v. below.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: That's right, I did not update the page before publishing my comment. Comment deleted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is just:

```
SELECT CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName, 
               IF(middleName is null, '', concat(' ', middleName)))
```

A simpler way would be:

```
SELECT TRIM(CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName, ' ', IFNULL(middleName, ' ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName, if(middleName IS NULL,'',' '), IFNULL(middleName, ''))
```

or

```
SELECT CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName, IFNULL(concat(' ', middleName), ''))
```

Comment: Your second method appends a 0 to every single record, while not doing anything with the middle name.

Comment: Updated the 2nd one to use concat() instead of the + operator. What about the 1st one?

Answer (score -1):

Use [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html):

```
SELECT CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName, 
    IF(middleName IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(' ',middleName), ''))
```

Comment: Doesn't give a middle name for a single record.